# where can i find the windows 7 iso md5 and sha1 hash?

Tags: windows

I have looked in a lot of places but it seems i can't find in microsoft site a detalied page with all the hash for all the windows 7 versions.
Can anyone point me to the right page?
Thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are downloading these from MSDN, then you can find the SHA hash when you click the *View* link in the Details column in the Downloads area.

Microsoft have this information readily available to anyone downloading Windows from one of the official authorised areas. If you are getting the download images from somewhere else then the official SHA is going to be of no use to you, as it depnds on what the image is and how it is made. Tthe SHA hash is simply a fingerprint of that particular image and in no way validates or authenticates the contents as being whole and untampered with.

Comment: The before-last sentence may be partially right if you consider ISO random images (but one can search for the precise sum anyway, this is the point).  The last sentence is totally wrong.  Both MD5 and SHA-1 will validate data integrity.  Although possibly breakable, those are cryptographic hashes and they do provide this feature.